# Android: draw "irregular" strokes on canvas, sort of chalk on blackboard

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to achieve an effect like this one:

[image: chalk on blackboard effect]

Anybody has an idea on how to draw such a line on a Canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getting a little closer:

```
    chalkPaint = new Paint();
    chalkPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    chalkPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    Bitmap chalkShader = ((BitmapDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chalk_texture)).getBitmap();
    chalkPaint.setShader(new BitmapShader(chalkShader, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
```

this paints a texture with a chalk effect:

[image: chalk texture]

now I "just" need the irregular border... still trying...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably harder to do than you think.

Drawing a line like this is mainly based on randomness. For example, between "M" and "N" in your picture, I think there are not one but four successive small lines of different brush sizes (chosen randomly in a small interval). Look closer, and you will see them.

The coordinates of these four small lines are also randomly adjusted (by a very small amount) to avoid having a straight line once put together.

There may also be a random number of small lines between two squares (I think there are more than four small lines between "R" and "X").

You may try to search for a library which already do the job, I don't know if there is one but it's not impossible.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions and just to clarify: I never thought I was easy to implement ;)